# How to test methods inner logic where class member is calling another method

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I would like to test a `agentAgentInfo` method as well need to test `wsProxy.findAgentInfo` method. How can I test it with PowerMockito/Mockito?

```
    private WSProxy wsProxy = new WSProxy();
    public String getAgentInfo(String loginId) {
        String agentInfo = null;
        try {
           agentInfo = wsProxy.findAgentInfo(loginId);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return agentInfo;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you created *hard to test* code.

There are two options here:

1. You use PowerMock/PowerMockito in order to allow you to inject a mocked WSProxy object at this call: `wsProxy = new WSProxy();` That mocked object should then expect a call to `findAgentInfo()`.
2. You change your design to use **dependency injection**. In other words: instead of your class *directly* calling **new**, you use some other mean to acquire such a WSProxy object (for example by receiving one through a constructor).

I usually recommend option 2; and you get there by learning how to create *testable* code (for example by watching these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79)). Yes, PowerMock works for such problems; but the problem is that PowerMock simply doesn't come for free - I have spent hours and hours debugging "issues" with PowerMock; to always figure that the breakage had nothing to do with our production code. So, as tempting as it is; not using PowerMock saves me **a lot** of time; that I can use to come up with better designs.

Comment: I would definitely go with option 2, as you say the OP is in for a lot of pain otherwise.

Comment: @JimNicholson Sure; but to a certain degree that is opinion. I got "complaints" more than once by people saying PowerMock works fine for them. But for some strange reason those people rarely to never have answers for those people asking about strange powermock issues.

Comment: @GhostCat thanks for your response. Here I cannot inject WSProxy object, this object is get initialize by init() method. So snippet is as follow

**public void init(String url){ wsProxy = new WSProxy(url);}**

Because if I initialize it via constructor then it will be open to external world which I do not want.

Could you suggest something on this lines???

Comment: You could change your init method to accept a WSProxy object; instead of just an URL. Or you could have a ProxyFactory object that comes via dependency injection that creates the Proxy object within your init method.